# What does this sign on a hiking trail communicate?

Tags: hiking

[image]

What does the rectangle with diagonal separating of black and white fillings say? Where can one find good glossary of hiking symbols?

Comment: That may be difficult to answer unless you tell us where you found this sign.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a sign used in Spain which means that the land is a private hunting reserve. That doesn't mean you can't walk on it, but it means you need authorisation to hunt (and that perhaps you should be alert to the presence of hunters, and that it might be best to stick to the path). It's hard to find English language sources, [but this website has an explanation of this sign](https://www.spainbuddy.com/hunting-signs-in-spain/).

Apparently, this sign may mean either

> Coto privado de caza – Reserved for private hunting

or

> Coto intensivo de caza – Reserved for intensive hunting

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a [trail marker or trail blaze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_blazing?wprov=sfti1) to me. Often they are simple colors but when colors aren’t sufficient, you can also use simple shapes.

You might be able to find a map or explanation somewhere that will tell you what trail fits which which trail marker.

Comment: This makes sense internationally. Even when (as in the other answer) in Spain there is a distinct explanation.